# how to control one of the handler in it is returned, and no other handler is executed

Tags: java

In netty4.1, how to control the handlers after one of them is returned.

For example, I have a `CheckUserServerHandler`, `DataMessageServerHandler`, etc., where `CheckUserServerHandler` is used to perform user data validation, and if the validation is **successful**, I can execute `DataMessageServerHandler` and so on.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a flag to express the result of user data validation, the DataMessageServerHandler should test the flag and then judge whether to do the following job.

Comment: This is a feasible solution.
But is there a solution that can not pass through handler?
Maybe we can research it

Comment: do you means Dynamic loading and unloading the handler ?(by ChannelPipeline)

Comment: I find it .  like this : if (true) { ctx.fireChannelRead(msg); } else return;

Comment: @O is null this is a perfect solution for your problem certainly，I learned that, thanks~